# What is a established way to store "3d" data in sphreadsheet for ease of future manipulation

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I got a bunch of data which i want to store for future analysis. The problem is  for each measurement i got 3 values (min, mean, max), measurement number (1-99) and date. So 99 sets of 3 values per each date.

example:

```
21-10-2016(date)
1(measurement No)
100(min)
150(mean)
200(max)
next:
21-10-2016(date)
2(measurement No)
106(min)
140(mean)
190(max)
```

and so on

i could do table like this:
`date| 1 min| 1 mean| 1 max| 2 min| 2 mean| 2 max | 3 min ...`

But maybe there is a better way to store such data?
I want to share this data so I'm wondering how to best format it in the way that most people will be comfortable with.

I'm using Google spreadsheets

Comment: What makes you say this is "3D" data?

Answer (score 1):

Lay it out one record per row:

```
+------------+-----------------+-----+------+-----+
| Date       | Measurement No. | Min | Mean | Max |
+------------+-----------------+-----+------+-----+
| 21-10-2016 | 1               | 100 | 150  | 200 |
+------------+-----------------+-----+------+-----+
| 21-10-2016 | 2               | 106 | 140  | 190 |
+------------+-----------------+-----+------+-----+
```